# How to update postgres dataset with native query in java and ignore hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I want to update a dataset in my postgres database. For this i created a native query:

```
        javax.persistence.Query query = entityManager
            .createNativeQuery("UPDATE ?1 SET ?2 = ?3 WHERE ?4 = ?5");
    query.setParameter(1, "myschema.books);
    query.setParameter(2, "id_author");
    query.setParameter(3, "27010");
    query.setParameter(4, "id_book");
    query.setParameter(5, "10 OR 34");
    query.executeUpdate();
```

I work with Hibernate and entities and my Book entity has a value

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "id_author", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "author_fkey"))
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
public Author author;
```

So do I need to initalize a new var Author and set id_author and give my query the "full" author? I jsut want to have a query like in postgres e.g.

```
UPDATE myschema.books SET id_author = 27010 WHERE id_book = 10 OR 34;
```

But always getting error after execute:

```
14:26:05.656 [http-nio-9080-exec-8] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: syntax error at or near "$2"
```

Position: 25

Comment: table names, params, should not be used with setParameter!

Comment: But i want a generic query, cause sometimes i want to update release date or name of author or something else

Comment: It is not my bad, but you can't do it with setParameter :)

Comment: And how should I do that?

Comment: You should accept that you can't have a "this query will do everything depending on what parameters I pass in". It's not good design either. You **will have to** hardcode table names, column names and such.